# Sample based on a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sample

Assume we have two data frames data1 and data2, both with same columns, e.g.

```
 > head(data1)
  ID Region Age Label
1  1     CC  20     0
2  2     BB  20     1
3  3     AA  40     0
4  4     BB  60     1
5  5     BB  40     0
6  6     BB  40     1
```

Assume all features are factors (except ID).

**Question:** How do I take a representative sample from data2 based on data1? E.g. based on product frequency of data1, see below: take 6 sample with Region:AA, Age:20, Label:0, take 1 sample with Region:AA, Age:20, Label:1, etc...

```
> head(count(data1, c("Region", "Age", "Label")))
  Region Age Label freq
1     AA  20     0    6
2     AA  20     1    1
3     AA  40     0    3
4     AA  40     1    5
5     AA  60     0    5
6     AA  60     1    3
```

I was looking at the `sampling` package as well as `dplyr` package. But I can't get my head around it. Formally, I am looking for a way for stratified sampling from data2 based on distribution of features in data1.

Thank you.

**Edit:** First, credit goes to @Jesse Tweedle for his concise answer below using `dplyr`. Here an alternative partial solution using libraries `sampling` (function `strata`) and `data.table` is presented:

```
library(sampling)
library(data.table)

d1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:100, 
                 region = sample(c("AA", "BB", "CC"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 age = sample(c(20,40,60),100,replace = TRUE), 
                 label = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE))
d1.table = as.data.table(d1)

d2 <- data.frame(ID = 1:1000, 
                 region = sample(c("AA", "BB", "CC"), 1000, replace = TRUE), 
                 age = sample(c(20,40,60),1000,replace = TRUE), 
                 label = sample(c(0,1), 1000, replace = TRUE))
d2.table = as.data.table(d2)

#Sort
setkey(d1.table, region, age)
setkey(d2.table, region, age)

d1.table.freq = d1.table[,.N,keyby = list(region, age)]

d2.sample = data.table(strata(d2.table,
                              c("region", "age"),
                              d1.table.freq$N,
                              "srswor")) # random sampling without replacement
```

Of course this implies that all combinations of features which appear in d1 (i.e. are not 0) have to appear in d2 **and** the other way around. From that point of view it is not a general solution but a partial one.

Comment: Why do you "take 6 sample with Region:AA" if there's only one `AA` sample in `data1`?

Comment: @PoGibas I take 6 samples with Region:AA, Age:20, Label:0. There are 6 of those but I only listed head of data1 above, that's why you see only one :)

Comment: It's hard to answer only with description of your data. Please post `data1` and `data2` using `dput`.

Comment: what do you mean by "product frequency" ?

Comment: @PoGibas this is just an example here, e.g. `data1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:100, Region = sample(c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"), 100, replace = TRUE)...`

Comment: @MKR see `freq` column in `count`

Answer (score 1):

## partly-dplyr answer

Here's some fake data, with a `counts` dataset:

```
data1 <- tibble(id = 1:30,
                region = sample(letters[1:3], 30, replace = TRUE),
                label = sample(0:1, 30, replace = TRUE))
counts <- data1 %>% group_by(region, label) %>% count()

data2 <- tibble(id = 1:300,
                region = sample(letters[1:3], 300, replace = TRUE),
                label = sample(0:1, 300, replace = TRUE))
```

`sample_n` usually helps here, but won't take separate `size` arguments for each group. So we join the `counts` dataset, `split` on the `region, label` variables, `map` `sample_n` to each list, using `size = n` (where `n` is from count), and then use `bind_rows` to put the list of dataframes back together:

```
data2 %>%
  left_join(counts) %>%
  split(list(data2$region, data2$label)) %>%
  map(~ sample_n(.x, size = unique(.x$n))) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

If your datasets are much different you may have to use `replace = TRUE` in the `sample_n` function.

Comment: Very nice idea. I get an error however: `Error: size is not a numeric or integer vector`... I am in the process of trying to fix it...

Comment: Does it work on my fake data and not your real data? Or does it fail on both?

Comment: On both as it looks like. Btw, real data is going to be transformed into something like example data, so there won't be much difference

Comment: Could be a difference in package versions. I'm using `R version 3.4.0` and `dplyr_0.7.4`, what are you on? You can find out by running `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: `R version 3.4.3` and `dplyr_0.7.4` running on linux ubuntu 16.4.3

Comment: I updated to R 3.4.3 and my solution still works for me. The only thing I can suggest is to make sure the same variables are in `group_by` in the `counts` dataset and `split` in the last step. 

Comment: Got it, had to use library `tidyverse`. Thank you! In the mean time I found also a solution using library `sampling` and `data.table`. Shall post it also above. Credit goes to your solution :)